# BASH commands inbetween SQLPlus code or how to count the time used to run different SQLplus commands?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

For performance testing purposes - I need to count duration of SQLPlus query. Its not so simple as it seems to be.

I have the code here:

```
VARIABLE RC REFCURSOR;
EXEC :RC := $aktuellesBericht;
SPOOL ${BERICHT}_${configArray[0]}.DATA
PRINT RC;
SPOOL OFF
```

It's just a part of the whole command. The whole command looks like this:

```
sqlplus -s /nolog > /dev/null 2>&1 <<EOF
CONNECT USER/PASSWORD@DATABASE
#A ton of unimportant SET and CLEAR commands goes here#
VARIABLE RC REFCURSOR;
EXEC :RC := $aktuellesBericht;
SPOOL ${BERICHT}_${configArray[0]}.DATA
PRINT RC;
SPOOL OFF
QUIT
EOF
```

I need to count time of `EXEC :RC := $aktuellesBericht;` and `PRINT RC;` separately. Is this even possibe? Can I count it somehow? Let me use some pseudocode showing what I want to do:

```
execstart = date +%s%N
EXEC :RC := $aktuellesBericht;
execend = date +%s%N

SPOOL ${BERICHT}_${configArray[0]}.DATA

printstart = date +%s%N
PRINT RC;
printend = date +%s%N
SPOOL OFF

exectime=$(( execend - execstart ))
printtime=$(( printend - printstart ))

echo $exectime;
echo $printtime;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get execution time of sql script in oracle sqlplus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401270/get-execution-time-of-sql-script-in-oracle-sqlplus)

Answer (score 0):

`bash` has a builtin `time` command which executes a command then print various times :

> If the time reserved word precedes a pipeline, the elapsed as well as
>   user and system time consumed by its execution are reported when the
>   pipeline terminates. The TIMEFORMAT variable may be set to a format string that specifies how the timing
>   information should be displayed;

```
# only the real time
TIMEFORMAT="This was done in : %R seconds"

time EXEC :RC := $aktuellesBericht;
```

Comment: I thought EXEC was some alias, I was misled by the `bash` tag and the bash-like pseudo code, sorry